# Prevent clear from clearing previous screens in bash ubuntu-16.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to determine a way to stop clear from erasing previous terminal command history on ubuntu-16.04

I want it to have similar behaviour Ctrl+L, but I have got into the habit of typing clear instead (since it had this behaviour on my Ubuntu-14.04 before I upgraded).

Is there any easy way to do this?

My initial thoughts were to alias clear to a different command, but I'm not sure what this command would be like.
Can anybody assist with this or will I just have to get used to using Ctrl+L?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man clear:

```
clears your screen if this is possible, including its scrollback
buffer (if the extended "E3" capability is defined).
```

To find out if this extended "E3" is defined and how to change this behavior, this might be useful to you: https://superuser.com/questions/1094599/how-do-i-change-the-behavior-of-clear-on-centos7-such-that-it-will-not-clear

Comment: It is similar yes, what I want is to be able to scroll back through the output of the commands. This is the difference I want to resolve, clear gets rid of the scroll back whereas Ctrl+L only clears the screen and preserves scrollback.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question, i have edited above

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for